# VBA code for dragging down contents of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wrote a macro to copy and paste (drag down) contents of a cell, the process should repeat itself several times. Yet, I get the "AutoFill Method or Range Class failed" message. What might cause it?

```
Sub DragDown()

    Range("A10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Range(Selection.Offset(0, 0), 
    Selection.Offset(2, 0))

    k = 0
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "00215F107"
        ActiveCell.Offset(k + 7, 0).AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0))
        k = k + 7
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: In which cell is `"00215F107"` located?

Comment: @VBasic2008 cell `"A40"` as well as `"A41"` till `"A46`" - the structure of the sheet is as follows: the A:A column has 7x the same number in a row, then 2 other cells (which need to be filled out by dragging the contents of the 3rd one down), then the same 7 numbers again.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing this

```
ActiveCell.Offset(k + 7, 0).AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0))
```

to this

```
Selection.AutoFill Range(Selection.Offset(0, 0), Selection.Offset(k + 7, 0))
```

solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure it will solve the issue. I just tried it out but it throws my excel into an endless loop which I only can break by closing the program. Also, I may not fully understand your code, but the values I need to drag down are changing with each iteration of the loop, that's why I chose to use "ActiveCell" to copy the respective contents each time. Thanks!

Comment: the result of this is now that excel drag down the same number but in each new cell it was increased by 1. Namely, it copied "58155Q103" all the way down, but made it "58155Q104", "58155Q105" etc.
"

Answer (score 0):

It can't work becuase destination of your Autofill must include the source range.
In your case - destination: *Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0))*
does not include source *ActiveCell.Offset(k + 7, 0)*.

You can use .Copy and .Paste commands. For example:

```
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)).Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(k + 7, 0).Paste
```

But if you want to copy tha same content multiple times, you can put your Copy command before your Do-Until loop.